# User dashboard: how to make sure user cannot access other people's data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, flask, oauth, token

A user can log in to their dashboard. When they log in, the front end pulls data from an S3 bucket corresponding to the user, like (e.g.) bucket/data/user5/data.json. This data is then rendered into a report on the front end.

How do I ensure that the user only sees their data and cannot see anyone else's? I am using AWS Cognito and React.

Extra information:

To allow the user to log in, I have asynchronous function that exchanges a given code for tokens by making a POST request to a predefined endpoint. If the response is successful, it stores the tokens and the user's email in `localStorage`. I have another asynchronous function that verifies the validity of a given token by making a POST request to another endpoint. It returns a boolean indicating whether the token is valid. If the verification fails, it prints an error and returns `false`. The server/backend for all of this is a Flask web application that integrates with an OAuth2 service to exchange authorization codes for tokens and to validate those tokens. It loads the client secret, which is an environment variable. It has one endpoint that accepts the POST request with an authorization code and exchanges it for tokens using the OAuth2 token endpoint, then another endpoint checks the validity of a provided access token. It retrieves the JWKS from Cognito, finds the correct public key using the key ID in the token's header, and then verifies the token using the `python-jose` library to decode and verify the JWT obtained from Cognito, checks client ID, and puts a CSP header on the response.